# How to read a file from the begining to the middle

Tags: c++

So I have read lines from beginning to end. It's ok. But now my purpose is that reading from beginning to middle. My file contains float number as follows. I thought if i calculate length of file, I would put it in a loop and read it as `filelenghth/2`.
But i can't because every line is 6 bit with enter space and numbers can change.it isn't now a good programming practice calculating according to data.

```
1.33
5.45
6.21
2.48
3.84
7.96
8.14
4.36
2.24
9.45
```

I need more efficiently a solution than as following code. What kind of solution do you advice for this purpose.

```
fstream inputNumbersFile("input.txt");
ifstream lengthOfNumbersFile("input.txt"); // for getting size of file
lengthOfNumbersFile.seekg(0, lengthOfNumbersFile.end);
int lengthFile = lengthOfNumbersFile.tellg();;
if (inputNumbersFile.is_open())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthFile;)
    {
        while (getline(inputNumbersFile, line))
        {               
            cout << line << endl;
            i = i + 6;
            if (i == lengthFile/2)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Read the file completely into a container and discard half of it. A much more complicated way would be to scan backwards in order to find the middle line, but there are few good reasons for that.

Comment: Sorry i couldn't understand reading into a container and discarding ?

Comment: Read the whole file, throw away the half you don't want.  If all of the lines are identical in length you could try and calculate the halfway point, but if any lines are different you'd probably guess wrong.

Comment: What part do you not understand? With container, I mean things like `std::list<>`, `std::vector<>`, `std::deque<>` etc. For the meaning of "discard", consult http://dict.org.

Comment: You're right man! Need a diffirent approach without calculating half point according to the lines length.

Comment: Is the length of each line in the file the same?  In your example it is...

Comment: Yes it's same but it can chage.For example if one line data can be 
1.45678. So I want to handle each line without thinking how long it is

Comment: Ulrich you mean that using a vector and getting half of the vector length ?

Comment: Do you need anything fancier than `std::vector<double> myDoubles; double myDouble; while (inputNumbersFile >> myDouble && inputNumbersFile.tellg() < lengthFile / 2) myDoubles.push_back(myDouble);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ios_base;
using std::ios;
using std::invalid_argument;
using std::getline;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
```

---

```
static string file_str(const string & path)
{
    ifstream ifs(&path[0], ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    if (!ifs)
        throw invalid_argument("File: " + path + " not found!");
    // Enable exceptions
    ifs.exceptions();

    // Init string buffer to hold file data.
    string buffer;
    // Set ifs input position indicator to end.
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::end);
    // Set the buffer capacity to exactly half the file contents size.
    buffer.resize(ifs.tellg() / 2);
    // Set ifs input position indicator to beginning.
    ifs.seekg(0);
    string::size_type buffer_size(buffer.size());
    // Read file contents into string buffer.
    ifs.read(&buffer[0], buffer_size);
    if (buffer[buffer_size - 1] != '\n')
    {
        // Continue reading until we find the next newline.
        string remaining;
        getline(ifs, remaining);
        // Append to buffer.
        buffer += remaining + '\n';
    }
    ifs.close();
    // Return by RVO.
    return buffer;
}
```

---

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    try
    {
        string file_contents = file_str(R"(C:\Users\...\Desktop\MyTextFile.txt)");
        cout << file_contents << endl;
    }
    catch (string message)
    {
        cerr << message << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which, with the following odd-newlined text file:

```
line one
line two
line three
line four
line five
```

Would read:

```
"line one\r\nline two\r\nline three\r\n"
```

And with the following even-newlined text file:

```
line one
line two
line three
line four
line five
line six
```

Would read:

```
"line one\r\nline two\r\nline three\r\n"
```